# Python iterating through dictionary to get certain values that meet requirements

Tags: python

I want to be able to put in the start and end year and have the names in the dictionary that are in between those years print out.

Dictionary:

dict = {'Charell Adagala': 2018, 'Sukhneet kaur': 2018, 'Mayanka Jha': 2019,
'Paul Cheakalos': 2018, 'Elizabeth(Liz)Boniface': 2013,
'Kati Illieva': 2021, 'Suzy wilson': 2018, 'Ronit Gopalani': 2019}

Start year: 2019
End year: 2021

Given those years how to print out {'Mayanka Jha', Kati Illieva', 'Ronit Gopalani'}

Comment: `[k for k,v in your_dict.items() if 2019<=int(v)<=2021]`

Answer (score 1):

Here a working implementation.
As a note I change the variable name form `dict` to `my_dict`, `dict` is a python keyword and therefore it is not recommended using it as a variable name since it may lead to unexpected behaviour.

```py
my_dict = {
    "Charell Adagala": 2018,
    "Sukhneet kaur": 2018,
    "Mayanka Jha": 2019,
    "Paul Cheakalos": 2018,
    "Elizabeth(Liz)Boniface": 2013,
    "Kati Illieva": 2021,
    "Suzy wilson": 2018,
    "Ronit Gopalani": 2019,
}

start_year = 2019
end_year = 2021

output = [k for k, v in my_dict.items() if v >= start_year and v <= end_year]
```

Comment: Please do not use `dict` as a variable name in Python. You stomp on the built-in function by that same name. Idiomatically, you can do `2019 <= v <= 2021` for greater clarity.

Comment: The poster of the question called it dict, so I think he was just trying to maintain consistency.

Comment: @kinshukdua: Good opportunity to both give an answer and some extra as well...

Comment: I agree, dict is not a good choice for a variable name. I was trying to maintain the same code from the question... Should I still change the variable name in the answer? (I'm still quite new to StackOverflow)

Comment: @MatteoZanoni: I replace an example from a post with `your_dict` and include the exact text I had in my first comment. You are off to a great start!

Comment: @dawg I edited the answer changing the variable name and including an explanation. Thanks for the advice